# Reference changes value when used to create object

Tags: c++

I'm getting some strange error while running some C++ code that uses references. Basically I have three classes, the first contains an object of the second one while the second contains a vector of objects of the third class. This is the example code:

```
class MainClass {

public:
    SecondaryClass myClass;

private:
    void myFunction() {
        int temp = 0;
        const int& newValue = myClass.getFinalClassByIndex(temp).getInt();
        // I add another FinalClass with the same value
        myClass.addClassToVector(newValue);
        // I try to add another one but the variabile "newValue" has another value
        myClass.addClassToVector(newValue);
    }

};

class SecondaryClass {

public:
    SecondaryClass() {
        myVector.push_back(FinalClass(0));
    }

private:
    std::vector<FinalClass> myVector;

    void addClassToVector(const int& value) {
        myVector.push_back(FinalClass(value));
    }

    FinalClass& getFinalClassByIndex(const int& index) {
        return myVector.at(index);
    }

};

class FinalClass {

public:
    FinalClass(const int& value) : myInt(value){}
    FinalClass(const int&& value) : myInt(value){}

    const int& getInt(){ return myInt; }

private:
    int myInt;

};
```

This is what happens when I run "myFunction": I get the integer value from the first object in the vector myVector and I put it in the newValue variable. Then I try to create two new FinalClass objects with the addClassToVector method, and these two will have the same integer value as the first one.
The first new object (that will be the second object in the vector) is created correctly; when I try to create the second object (the third one in the vector) the newValue variable does not have the value 0 as it should be, but it has a totally different one. It seems like the value has been moved instead of copied into the new class.
The second constructor in the class FinalClass is used when I create the class like ' FinalClass(0) ', it gives me an error if I don't use the "&&" notation.
What could the problem be in this case? I think it has something to do with the way I handle the references, but I don't understand why.

Comment: What is the `std::vector<FinalClass> myVector` capacity before and after you add the new class?

Comment: @SilvanoCerza capacity as in size? If so, it's like I'm creating a MainClass object in the main function of the project, so the attribute myClass is initialized with its default constructor and, as soon as is created, it takes the first FinalClass object (the line myVector.push_back(FinalClass(0));)

Comment: Capacity as the number of elements that the container has currently allocated space for, you can know it calling  `vector::capacity()`. Radosław Cybulski explained the issue quite well anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You return everything by reference. Which is fine until your vector needs to be resized, which reallocates your vector's memory and invalidates all references to that memory. Including your `newValue` reference. As a result your `const int& newValue` points to memory, which contains random data and it's a miracle your program doesn't crash at all.

Stop using references when you don't need them:

```
newValue = myClass.getFinalClassByIndex(temp).getInt();
```

and

```
int getInt(){ return myInt; }
```

even better:

```
auto getInt(){ return myInt; }
```

Comment: Alright, and does the vector needs to be resized only when I put objects in it or only when I remove them?

Comment: Removing using `pop_back` doesn't invalidate iterators which means that vector won't reallocate memory. The same story goes for `erase`.

Comment: In my project, I don't need to remove elements from the vector, that's why I asked you if the resize happens only when I remove objects or even when I add them

Comment: When you add them. If you know ahead the maximum number of elements and have spare memory, you can use `reserve`. This will preallocate memory for the vector and until you reach amount of elements passed to `reserve` you will be able to add new elements without worring for reallocation.